# TableAdapter.Insert (into ACCESS DB) get current Seed value for ID

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, seed

I am trying to alter an existing programm in VB , I am not experienced in this language , but unfortunately I cannot convert it for now.

I created the DB Connections with the Designer , which automatically created the BindingSource, TableAdapter , DataSet .

I insert something into this table like this :

```
Me.Validate()

myBindingSource.EndEdit()

myTableAdapter.Insert(1, 1, "test", 100, Now, 1, Now)
```

I would now like to get CURRENT_SEED valuer for the ID field ( which is Autoincrement ) 
can I do it somehow here without making some extra connection , is it returned somewhere ?

Regards
Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use table adapters for ease, just created a "Select Max(ID) From myTable" scalar query then just call it to get the last value.

```
int resultID = myTableAdapter.GetLastID();
```